# Why can scripts inserted with document.write change variables

Tags: javascript

Why is the below script printing 33 rather than 31?

```
<script>
var i = 1;
document.write("<script> i=3; document.write(i); </scr" + "ipt>");
document.write(i);
</script>
```

This one prints 31, what is the difference?

```
<script>
var i = 1;
document.write("<script> i=3; document.write(i); </scr" + "ipt>" + i);
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think it should print 31?

Comment: @Juhana as i=1 as declared

Comment: And then changed to 3...

Comment: @Clive but it is being changed in document.write..what is happening in details there?

Comment: Same context and same variable name so yeah the value is changed.What is happening is just you wrote code that change the value of i to 3. `document.write` doesn't provide any context, everything you wrote run in the global context.

Comment: @gillesc I have changed the question, could help see what's the different between 2 codes?

Comment: Cos in the second the script isn't run until it is injected into the document so you are printing `i` before it get changed to 3

Comment: Either way one should never do stuff like that in real application.

Answer (score 2):

This is the order of how it's working:

1. You define a variable called `i` with a value of `1`.
2. You write a new script to the document

   2.1. This new script redefines `i` to `3`.

   2.2. The script writes `i` (keep in mind, now `3`) to the document.
3. You write `i` again (value is still the same from when you redefined it, `3`) to the document.
4. End result is `33`, because you wrote `3` twice.

This is the order of the second block:

1. You define a variable `i` with the value `1`.
2. JavaScript concatenates the string and `i`, creating `"<script> i=3; document.write(i); </script>1"` (Notice the `1` at the end, this is to do concatenation)
3. JavaScript writes the new concatenated string to the document.

   3.1. `i` is redefined as `3`.

   3.2. `document.write`'s `i` (which was redefined to `3` previously).
4. You end up with `"3<script> i=3; document.write(i); </script>1"` as your final document, due to the concatenation and `document.write`.  And obviously, `<script>`'s contents aren't visible.  So you end up with `31`.

Comment: How it is being redefined, can provide more clear information?

Comment: `i=3;`@william, what more is there to know? Are you happy with scope in JavaScript, if not put a few hours aside and have a read :)

Comment: @Clive I have changed the question, could help see what's the different between 2 codes?

Comment: i think gillesc has covered it in the comments above

Answer (score 2):

In order for the output of your first example to be 31, the outermost script block would have to run all the way through, generating all its output, before the parser did anything with that output. And that's a perfectly reasonable way to think it would work (I thought it worked that way for years); it just isn't correct. :-) Browsers are more proactive than that.

The browser's parser and JavaScript engine have to work together to handle script tags that don't use the `async` or `defer` attribute. Two key things about that:

1. When the parser sees a complete `script` block, it screeches to a halt and hands that off to the JavaScript engine to run immediately.
2. Calls to `document.write` feed new tokens to the parser; if the parser sees a complete token, it will handle it **during the call to `document.write`**. If that complete token is a script block, "handling it" involves calling the JavaScript engine again, during the current call to it. You can think of each `document.write` call as a call to the parser, and each complete script block as a call to the JavaScript engine. Like function calls, these can be nested.

That second point is why you're seeing 33 rather than 31. The script you're writing with `document.write` is executed **during** that call to `document.write`, not afterward, and so `i` is updated to `3` (and output) before that `document.write` completes. So by the time you get to the `document.write` at the end of your main script block, `i` has already been changed to `3`, and has already been output once.

In your second example, you're using `i` **before** you call `document.write` (when you append it to the text), so of course you see the value of `i` as it is then, `1`.

This may make the order of calls clearer:

```
<script>
document.write("<script>document.write('a');</scr" + "ipt>");
document.write('b');
</script>
```

The result is `ab`, not `ba`. The code output by the first `document.write` runs **before** the last `document.write` runs, so the output of the middle `document.write` appears before the output of the last one.

Comment: Good explanation of what's actually going on behind the scenes, where my answer just explains the flow of what's happening.  :)

Answer (score 0):

in the first case injected `document.write` inside the first one redefines the variable i, so the second `document.write` prints also 3.
in the second case you have only one document.write which appends original value of i=1 to the output of injected `document.write`.
funny thing, someone may expect here even another combination '13')))